# Have a string and trying to input that input a tableview

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

So here's the problem that I am having, I have to read from multiple different files and each file has a different format of how it represents the data, so for example one file could be:

1 2 3 4 5

and another could be:

0

and another from the file can be is:

```
col1 col2 col3

0    2     1
```

how can I use a tableview to output this type of data.

**EDIT**

Here are a couple of examples from actually data, for each of these examples the whole data is one big string with \n and \t where the tabs and newlines are located

Example 1:

```
address 1         address 2                   size     id     flag
0000000000000000 0000000000000000            16384     1 --w--pY--
0000000000000000 0000000000000000            16384     2 --w--pY--
0000000000000000 0000000000000000            16384     3 --w--pY--
0000000000000000 0000000000000000            16384     4 --w--pY--
0000000000000000 0000000000000000            16384     5 --w--pY--
0000000000000000 0000000000000000            16384     6 --w--pY--
```

For this example I would want the data to outputted like how it looks like in the tableview

Example 2:

```
2135300000 45400000 894600000
```

For this example I would want the data to outputted like how it looks like in the tableview

Example 3:

```
5
```

As you can see for each of these examples the way the data is stored is completely different, so is there a way to input each type of format into a tableview without having to know how the data is represented?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Could you provide an example of what do you want to get and how do you want to display the data?

Comment: @RomhaKorev I have edited the post.